# Load system wide keyboard layout prior to Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pinvoke, keyboard-layout

We're creating a control panel applet which **adds new keyboard languages to the local system**. After reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I realized we should use `LoadKeyboardLayout` function. But it's mentioned in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that:

> Prior to Windows 8: This function only affects the layout for the
>   current process or thread.
>   Beginning in Windows 8: This function
>   affects the layout for the entire system.

Since we need this change to be system wide and we need to support Windows XP SP3 (we are using .NET 4.0), it seems we can't use that function.
What's the alternative that works well in Windows XP SP3 up to Windows 8.1? (preferably including server versions)

Comment: The control panel already supports this functionality.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, our application does the same thing. It basically gives the same functionality control panel offers in a user friendly, fully Persian environment with measures taken for handicap, etc users ...